# a special greedy strategy for interval scheduling

Tags: algorithm, scheduled-tasks

Recently, I am studying interval scheduling problem.

Problem description: There is a set of tasks in a collection, and now there is only one machine to handle them. The machine has no limited time and every task can be performed at any time. The goal is to choose a scheduling order that maximizes the number of tasks completed.

Commonly, the greedy strategy for this problem is choosing the task with earliest finish time and then recursive. However, if I choose a task which overlaps as few other tasks as possible and then recursive, it seems that does work. Does anyone help me prove it is wrong or its correctness?

Comment: There is something missing in the problem description. What are the characteristics of each task? For example, can every task be performed at any time? Presumable each task has a know duration. Is there a maximum length of time the machine can operate? Please edit your question to make it clear and complete.

Comment: I don’t understand. If the server doesn’t have a time limit, won’t all tasks be completed eventually? So how does scheduling order affect the number completed? Can you give a concrete example of what you mean?